# Error deploying EAR project in Eclipse with Wildfly 10.0

Tags: jboss, ejb, wildfly, ear

I'm trying to deploy an ear, but eclipse gives me an error:

```
16:23:15,844 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment licensemgr-ear.ear (runtime-name: licensemgr-ear.ear) in 1ms
16:23:15,847 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "licensemgr-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "licensemgr-ear.ear")
16:23:15,850 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."licensemgr-ear.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."licensemgr-ear.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "licensemgr-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/C:/AS/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/licensemgr-ear.ear"], module file licensemgr-bl.jar not found
    at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:186)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more

16:23:15,851 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"licensemgr-ear.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"licensemgr-ear.ear\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"licensemgr-ear.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR [\"/C:/AS/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/licensemgr-ear.ear\"], module file licensemgr-bl.jar not found"}}
16:23:15,882 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "licensemgr-ear.ear" with deployment "licensemgr-ear.ear"
16:23:15,883 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."licensemgr-ear.ear".STRUCTURE
      service jboss.deployment.unit."licensemgr-ear.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."licensemgr-ear.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "licensemgr-ear.ear"
```

This is my application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>licensemgr-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>licensemgr-bl.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>licensemgr-web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>licensemgr-web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Help.... me :'v
The missing jar is in the deploy folder, but wildfly don't find it

Answer (score 0):

If you are packaging as an EAR then all the jars, wars etc must be inside the ear itself, not as other files in the deployments directory